# NodeJS Websocket client stay in pending mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

i have a simple js script that "try" to connect to listening server (SocketTest) as shown in the image below. It's really simple, just one line :

```
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:6601');
```

So, yes, it is connected but it stay in pending mode finishing by "failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out"

Maybe i'm wrong somewhere but i don't see it... and it's really simple.
If someone got an idea....

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without implementing open event do not expect any answer from the server :)
Try this:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:6601');

ws.on('open', function open() {
  ws.send('something');
});
```

**Edit:** The `nodejs` tag fooled me I thought it is server side.

The same true on client side, you need to handle `onopen` event:

```
// Connection opened
exampleSocket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
    socket.send('Hello Server!');
});

// Listen for messages
exampleSocket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
});
```

Comment: It''s on client side so, i cant use require... even with the onmessage function. thanks @lependu